# Signal R library for chat is not working for group with mvc asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, chat, signalr

I am using SignalR jQuery library for sending chat with group but I can not see chat can sent in my case here is code...

I have made class for group and passed group from jQuery but seems some thing wrong, I can not see chat can be sent with chat window any one help me ...

Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

namespace Chat.Hubs
{
    [HubName("myChatHub")]
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(MyMessage message)
        {
            // Call the addMessage method on all clients            
            //Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(message.Msg);
            Clients.Group(message.GroupName).addNewMessageToPage("Group Message " + message.Msg);
        }

        //server
        public void Join(string groupName)
        {
            Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
        }
    }
    public class MyMessage
    {
        public string Msg { get; set; }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Chat";
}

<h2>Chat</h2>

<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="message" />
    <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
    <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
    <ul id="discussion">
    </ul>
</div>

@section scripts {
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--The jQuery library is required and is referenced by default in _Layout.cshtml. -->
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.min.js")"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.--> 
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.  
            var chat = $.connection.myChatHub;



            // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
            chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (message) {
                // Add the message to the page. 
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
            };
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            // Set initial focus to message input box.  
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start(function () {
                chat.server.join("RoomA");
            });

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                    chat.server.send({ Msg: $('#message').val(), Group: "RoomA" });
                    //chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
        // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
        function htmlEncode(value) {
            var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
            return encodedValue;
        }
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript object has GroupName not group:

```
Clients.Group(message.GroupName).addNewMessageToPage("Group Message " + message.Msg);
```

And you're sending:

```
chat.server.send({ Msg: $('#message').val(), Group: "RoomA" });
```

Notice the Group vs GroupName property.

Also, the task returned from Groups.Add completes when that client is in the group. This means you can return the Task from the method in order to know when the client is in that group.

Comment: HI, Right.. you are ... can any complete chat application is avaliable for urgent implementaion...like facebook chat or gmail chat?